# Cairo to Aqaba direct flights in 2019

Tags: air-travel, egypt, jordan

Planning a trip for my wife's 40th birthday to Egypt and Jordan from the US. I had hoped to stay in Aqaba as it's quicker to Petra than Amman and we'd get a little beach time.  I read online (in an article that I'm unable to hunt down at this point) that there are direct flights to Aqaba 2 times a week from Cairo.  Have been unable to hunt these down on any of the major airline or aggregator sites.  Does anyone know if this is still a thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're in luck!  [Air Cairo](https://www.flyaircairo.com/en/) has *just* launched [twice-weekly flights from Cairo to Aqaba](https://www.routesonline.com/news/38/airlineroute/286562/air-cairo-adds-aqaba-service-from-oct-2019/):

```
SM219 CAI1145 – 1345AQJ E70 2
SM219 CAI2200 – 2359AQJ E70 5

SM220 AQJ0100 – 0100CAI E70 6
SM220 AQJ1445 – 1445CAI E70 2
```

...meaning they fly every Tuesday and Friday.